# PCL failing compilation - Fedora 16 - Segmentation fault

Tags: gazebo, pcl, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been desperately trying to get some ROS packages working on Fedora 16 x86_64. I fixed some of the issues, but this seems like the only problem left.

I'm trying to compile pcl library and eventually gazebo..

So far...
rosmake pcl
Results in this error:
This is the end of the output of the log file:

```
-- CMinPack found (include: /home/TheLegace/ros/perception_pcl/cminpack/include, libs: optimized;/home/TheLegace/ros/perception_pcl/cminpack/lib/libcminpack.so;debug;/usr/lib64/libcminpack.so)
-- Try OpenMP C flag = [-fopenmp]
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED - Success
-- Try OpenMP CXX flag = [-fopenmp]
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED - Success
-- Found OpenMP: -fopenmp 
-- Found OpenNI: /usr/lib64/libOpenNI.so 
-- OpenNI found (include: /usr/include/ni, lib: /usr/lib64/libOpenNI.so)
-- Found Qhull: /usr/lib64/libqhull.so 
-- QHULL found (include: /usr/include/qhull, lib: optimized;/usr/lib64/libqhull.so;debug;/usr/lib64/libqhull.so)
-- ROS_ROOT /home/TheLegace/ros/ros
-- Found ROS; USE_ROS is ON
-- Found ROS package std_msgs path: /home/TheLegace/ros/ros_comm/messages/std_msgs
-- Found ROS package sensor_msgs path: /home/TheLegace/ros/common_msgs/sensor_msgs
-- Found ROS package roscpp_serialization path: /home/TheLegace/ros/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp_serialization
-- Found ROS package cpp_common path: /home/TheLegace/ros/ros_comm/utilities/cpp_common
-- Found ROS package rostime path: /home/TheLegace/ros/ros_comm/utilities/rostime
-- Found ROS package roscpp_traits path: /home/TheLegace/ros/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp_traits
-- Found ROS package roscpp path: /home/TheLegace/ros/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp
-- Found ROS package rosconsole path: /home/TheLegace/ros/ros_comm/tools/rosconsole
-- Found ROS package std_msgs path: /home/TheLegace/ros/ros_comm/messages/std_msgs
-- Found ROS package rosbag path: /home/TheLegace/ros/ros_comm/tools/rosbag
-- Found ROS package topic_tools path: /home/TheLegace/ros/ros_comm/tools/topic_tools
-- Found ROS package pcl path: /home/TheLegace/ros/perception_pcl/pcl
/bin/sh: line 31: 15923 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=`pwd`/../../.. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DUSE_ROS=ON -DFLANN_INCLUDE_DIR=`rospack find flann`/include -DFLANN_LIBRARY=`rospack find flann`/lib/libflann.so -DCMINPACK_INCLUDE_DIR=`rospack find cminpack`/include -DCMINPACK_LIBRARY=`rospack find cminpack`/lib/libcminpack.so -DBUILD_TESTS=OFF -DBUILD_OPENNI=ON -DBUILD_apps=OFF -DBUILD_common=ON -DBUILD_features=ON -DBUILD_filters=ON -DBUILD_global_tests=OFF -DBUILD_io=ON -DBUILD_octree=ON -DBUILD_kdtree=ON -DBUILD_keypoints=ON -DBUILD_range_image=ON -DBUILD_registration=ON -DBUILD_sample_consensus=ON -DBUILD_segmentation=ON -DBUILD_surface=ON -DBUILD_visualization=ON -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=ON ..
make: *** [installed] Error 139
```

I appreciate any help trying to fix it.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12981/pcl-failing-compilation---fedora-16---segmentation-fault/) by [TheLegace](https://answers.ros.org/users/1771/thelegace/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2012-02-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here, on my Fedora 16 system, I managed to setup gazebo and it runs without any problems. What version of PCL are you using? I have

$ svn info
Path: .
URL: http://svn.pointclouds.org/ros/branches/electric/perception_pcl
Repository Root: http://svn.pointclouds.org/ros
Repository UUID: 96ee21a3-c2b3-4322-a94e-acd7bc47b802
Revision: 168
Node Kind: directory
Schedule: normal
Last Changed Author: mdixon
Last Changed Rev: 150
Last Changed Date: 2011-11-21 16:03:31 +0100 (Mon, 21 Nov 2011)

And for Gazebo:

$ svn info
Path: .
URL: https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/simulator_gazebo/tags/electric
Repository Root: https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg
Repository UUID: eb33c2ac-9c88-4c90-87e0-44a10359b0c3
Revision: 38190
Node Kind: directory
Schedule: normal
Last Changed Author: hsu
Last Changed Rev: 38190
Last Changed Date: 2011-11-07 23:03:40 +0100 (Mon, 07 Nov 2011)

---

Originally posted by [Steven Bellens](https://answers.ros.org/users/55/steven-bellens/) with karma: 735 on 2012-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0